# BibTeX leaves out fields

Tags: natbib

I'm using `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` package to use an external `.bib` file for my bibliography. However, some fields of the entries are not shown in the bibliography. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx,array}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{framed,svg,float,tabularx,eurosym,changepage,cite}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\citep{EUROHS14}

\bibliography{biblio} 
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\end{document}
```

With the following biblio.bib file:

```
@article{EUROHS14,
author = {Milanovski, Dragan},
title = {eBriefing for ATC training},
journaltitle = {Hindsight 14},
year = {2011/2012},
editor = {EUROCONTROL},
pages = {60-65},
url = {https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/publication/files/111215-hs14.pdf},
}
```

This results in:

[image]

Thus, leaving out the `journaltitle` and editor, which to me, seems to be vital information. Can anyone point out how to display this information in the bibliography?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are using `natbib`/BibTeX and not `biblatex`, so I have removed the tag and corrected the title (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 for additional explanations). Because you are not using `biblatex` the field for the journal title is called simply `journal` and not `journaltitle`. Traditionally the bibliography styles do not show the `editor` for `@article`s.

Comment: Thanks! That already solves it, is there any way how I can display the editor anyway?

Comment: Change `editor = {EUROCONTROL},` to `note = {Editor: {EUROCONTROL}},`?

Comment: [`l2tabu`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf) suggests to use `natdin` instead of `dinat`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using BibTeX with `natbib` the field for the journal title is just `journal` and not `journaltitle` (`journaltitle` is a `biblatex` field name, but `biblatex` also accepts `journal`).

You should also separate the volume number from the journal title.

```
@article{EUROHS14,
  author    = {Milanovski, Dragan},
  title     = {eBriefing for ATC training},
  journal   = {HindSight},
  volume    = {14},
  year      = {2011/2012},
  pages     = {60-65},
  url       = {https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/publication/files/111215-hs14.pdf},
}
```

Traditionally, bibliographies do not show the editor or publisher of journal articles (I'd have said EUROCONTOL is more of an publisher rather than an editor, but be that as it may). If you insist on `EUROCONTROL`, you can add it to the `note` field, which will make it appear at the end or you can squeeze it into the `journal` field like so

```
journal   = {HindSight (EUROCONTROL)},
```

or

```
journal   = {EUROCONTROL: HindSight},
```

or

```
journal   = {EUROCONTROL's HindSight},
```

If the title *HindSight* is known in your field I would not bother with the *EUROCONTROL*.

Answer (score 3):

Note with bibtex the bib file can use *any* field names: extra fields are silently ignored.

The handling of fields is not controlled by bibtex itself but by the bibtex style you are using which is `dinat.bst` in your case. The list of entries accepted is listed at the head of that file which will be installed at a location such as

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/dinat/dinat.bst
```

the list is:

```
ENTRY
  % fields (crossref is default)
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    isbn
    issn
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    urldate
    volume
    year
  }
```

Comment: It should be noted that the list of used/printed fields may very well vary from entry type to entry type. In particular `editor` is in general a known field for the style, but it is not used for `@article`. My `dinat` lists the fields for `@article` as follows: `% required: author, title, journal, year
% optional: volume, number, pages, month, note, url, issn` which seems to check out.

Comment: @moewe yes thanks, I should probably clarify it